# jquery append element position always 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery's append() method, to add elements (div) to parent element (div as well).

When calling the offset function of the parent div, i'm getting it's relative position just fine. When i'm calling the child element, i'm getting 0 as its relative position (top and left)

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? How can I get the position of dynamically added div?

```
var $grid = $('#myDiv');
$grid.empty()
$grid.append("<div id="newDiv">...")
console.log($("#newDiv").position())
```

Output: top: 0 left: 0

(it shows me the current scroll bar offset from the top)

Comment: show us the code than telling the foo bar is a blah...

Comment: that wouldn't be enough to answer you....

Comment: This `$grid.append("<div id="newDiv">...")` won't work - you need to either encapsulate the string with single quotes `'` or specify the id attribute with single quotes `'`.

Comment: Could you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The returned value is correct. From the [jquery documentation for `.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

Unless it has styles, it's always going to be at 0,0.

You might want to use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead.

Comment: .offset() returns 0,0 as well.

the odd thing is that the property offsetTop as it appears in chrome Properies tab, is currect. i just need to find a way to get a hold of it

Comment: Just checking, the parent element is not at 0,0 though, right?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? (Run it directly below)

```js
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    $(".parent").append("<div class='child'></div>");
}

$("div.child").each( function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var top = $this.position().top;
  
    console.log(top);
  
    $this.text( "Distance from top : " + top )
})
```

```css
div.child{
    height : 20px;
    outline: blue solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Comment: i tried running this via console:
    $this = $("#newDiv") (enter)
    $this.position().top and it returns 0

Comment: the thing is, that when i scroll down the value of position().top changes from some reason to the relative distance from the scroll position to the top of the page

Comment: when checking is the properties (chrome) i can see the correct offsettop, but when trying to get it via jquery it returns 0, or when $("#newDIv").offsetTop is undefined

i'm using chrome on centos 7

Comment: I have added a console.log() in my example, and it outputs correct values (8,28,48,68,88) Run it and watch your console. Please make a fiddle or something, so we can see your code in action. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of whan i'm trying to do

```js
 

var $parent = $("parentDiv")

$parent.empty()

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    $parent.append("<div class='child'></div>");
}

$("div.child").each( function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var top = $this.position().top;
  
    console.log(top);
  
    $this.text( "Distance from top : " + top )
})
```

```css
div.child{
    height : 20px;
    outline: blue solid 1px;
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="parentDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to figure this out

the problem is probably caused by backbone.js, i'm using data-cid to retrieve the elements, and these attributes from some reason are not sowing up (or as 0)

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
var $grid = $('#myDiv');
$grid.empty()
var new_div = $grid.append("<div id='newDiv'>...")
console.log($(new_div).position())
```

As "new_div" variable has the appended element returned by the append function.